# How can I use a while loop in Python using Sympy to differentiate an equation 5 times, each run differentiating once?

Tags: python, sympy

I got stuck on a question where I needed to import Sympy and differentiate
Y = x^8 + 3x^7 + 3x^5 + 15 five times using a while loop, each loop differentiating the equation once. I got stuck at:

```
import sympy as sym

y = ( x**8 + 3*x**7 + 3*x**5 + 15 )

while y:
    y = sym.diff ( x**8 + 3*x**7 + 3*x**5 + 15 )
```

Any takers? I'm a newbie and don't really know how to approach this.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a while loop? You can just do `y.diff(x, 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x')
y_next =  x**8 + 3*x**7 + 3*x**5 + 15

i=0
while i<5:
    y_next = sym.diff ( y_next )
    i = i + 1
    print(y_next)
```

Result:

```
8*x**7 + 21*x**6 + 15*x**4
56*x**6 + 126*x**5 + 60*x**3
336*x**5 + 630*x**4 + 180*x**2
1680*x**4 + 2520*x**3 + 360*x
6720*x**3 + 7560*x**2 + 360
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This helped me understand how to print out the differentiated functions, I would upvote this but I cannot yet. Someone who can please upvote this, it is deserved.

Comment: You still can accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Also you can replace "while" by "for i in range(5):"

Answer (score 0):

y is not a True false statement you should use

```
import sympy as sym

y = ( x**8 + 3*x**7 + 3*x**5 + 15 )
i = 0

while i<5:
    y = sym.diff ( x**8 + 3*x**7 + 3*x**5 + 15 )
    i+=1
```

ps.im not familiar with sympy so I cant correct your y